# Including C File/Linking with CMake isn't working with C++: cannot include function

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

This is my C++ code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {     
    int width, height;
    unsigned char *rgba;
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/pic.tif", "rb");
    if(!fp)
        std::cout<<"failed"<<std::endl;
    rgba = floadtiff(fp, &width, &height);
    fclose(fp);

    if(rgba == 0)
        printf("TIFF file unreadable\n");
}
```

I am using [this](https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/tiffloader) library by @MalcolmMcLean, and that's what my loadtiff.c is.I have compiled it using gcc and am trying to link that library.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (test)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} cmake/)
add_executable(test tiffs.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test loadtiff)
```

and these are the errors I get when trying to make the program:

```
error: ‘floadtiff’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why can't I access this function, which is defined in loadtiff.c?

Comment: Are you sure you're including the right file? `#include` is typically used to include header files, not source files.

Comment: And if this is C++, why are you including C headers files (ie stdio.h) as well as C++ header files?

Comment: @ChrisTurner I thought stdio.h was a C++ header file, I had no idea! and yeah I think that's the right file, he said to just drop it in and compile?

Comment: In your tiffs.cpp file you need to include `#include "loadtiff.h"` not loadtiff.c

Comment: What happened when you compiled it with gcc? Those errors you're getting are specifically due to you trying to compile C code as C++ (they're really not the same at all)

Comment: @ChrisTurner sorry, when I took out my includes I got rid of those errors. Updated.

Comment: @vre sorry, when I took out my includes I got rid of those errors. Updated

Comment: C and C++ have a shared heritage, but they are different languages.  Although it is possible to write valid C code that is also valid and has the same semantics when interpreted as C++ code, it is unreasonably optimistic to suppose that C code not carefully crafted for that would nevertheless be suited for such treatment.  `extern "C"` is not at all relevant to that issue.

Comment: Please compile your loadtiff library as a static library not as shared object. by adding `add_library(loadtiff STATIC loadtiff.c)` to your CMakeLists.txt. Then in your `tiffs.cpp` file add the `extern "C" { #include "loadtiff.h" } ` lines.

Comment: @vre It didn't end up making a difference :/ still getting that floadtiff error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `tipps.cpp` add:

```
extern "C" {
#include "loadtiff.h" 
}
```

In `CMakeLists.txt` change to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project(tiffs)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} cmake/)
add_library(loadtiff tiffloader/loadtiff.c)
target_include_directories(loadtiff PUBLIC tiffloader/loadtiff.h)

add_executable(tiffs tiffs.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tiffs loadtiff)
```

where "tiffloader/" is wherever you put the "loadtiff" files.

Do not name projects or targets after reserved words like "test", or you will get CMake warnings.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!!!!!! Ironically, after all of this, the library doesn't work for my type of images.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got 2 problems.

1) your code is an abhorrent mixture of C and C++. For example, you're outputting text using C++

```
std::cout<<"failed"<<std::endl;
```

and C

```
printf("TIFF file unreadable\n");
```

Pick just one language and stick to it. Given it appears that `floadtiff` is expecting a `FILE *`, you'll probably be better off writing your code in C.

2) You're trying to use a library without telling the compiler anything about it. That's what header files are for. They tell the compiler you're using code from a different file and how the functions in that file are called. There should be a "loadtiff.h" file somewhere - you need to include that. That will contain definitions for the functions inside "loadtiff.c", such as `floadtiff`.

Without those definitions, your compiler has no idea if you're passing in the right number and/or type of parameters to those functions. It doesn't know what the return type of the function is or if it doesn't have one.

In C++ this information is especially important as you have function overloading, so it has to know exactly which function you're calling. In C, it's not quite so rigid and will make assumptions - which are often incorrect - about the function, but it will still warn you that it's done this.

Comment: After following your suggestions, and doing `extern "C" {#include "loadtiff.h"}`, I still get the error that floadtiff wasn't defined.

Comment: does "loadtiff.c" have a function called "floadtiff" in it? Does "loadtiff.h" have the matching definition for it in there too?

Comment: Yup! You can verify if you want from the link in my question,

Answer (score 0):

If I use the following source

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  #include "loadtiff.h"
}

int main(int argc, char argv[] ) {     
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* rgba;
    FILE* fp = fopen("/home/user/pic.tif", "rb");
    if(!fp)
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
    rgba = floadtiff(fp, &width, &height);
    fclose(fp);

    if(rgba == 0)
        printf("TIFF file unreadable\n");
    return 0;
}
```

with the following CMakeLists.txt file under Visual Studio 14 and CMake 3.8.2

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12.2)
project (test)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} cmake/)
add_executable(test tiffs.cpp)
add_library(loadtiff STATIC loadtiff.c)
target_link_libraries(test loadtiff)
```

CMake generates a fully functional solution and Visual Studio is able to build it without errors.

Edit:

I assumed you have tiffs.cpp, loadtiff.c and loadtiff.h located in the same directory.